# Парсинг HTML страницы

Tags: поиск, php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер. Сейчас решил поломать голову над одним алгоритмом парсинга, но вот беда. Не могу понять, в чем проблема.
Собственно вот код:

```
$alltext=file_get_contents($url);
$alltext = trim($alltext);
$alltext = strip_tags($alltext);
$alltext = ereg_replace('/&\w;/', '', $alltext); 
preg_match_all("/(\b[\w+]+\b)/",$alltext,$words);
```

А проблема состоит в том, что функция не берет весь текст. Вообще не понятно, что он делает. Русский буквы тоже не берет. Только ошибки иногда вытаскивает, а основной страницы не может. По-разному делал. Не получилось. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Есть такая страничка:

```
 <h1>TEXT</h1>
    Тут будет мой текст
    ололо push push
    <b>My frog<b><i>is die</i><br> 
    http://site.ru/
```

Вообще, функция должна вытаскивать все слова из этой страницы без тегов. 
Следующей функцией он выдал мне только: б,де,мой,ек,ололо,push,push,y,frogis,die,http,site,ru

```
 $alltext=file_get_contents($url);
    // убираем пробелы в начале и конце текста
    $alltext = trim($alltext);
    // удаляем тэги из текста
    $alltext = strip_tags($alltext);
    // удаляем последовательности вида &lt; &gt; &#1a22; при этом только если длина меньше 9 символов
    $alltext = preg_replace('/&[a-z0-9#]{1,9}?;/i', '', $alltext);
    // в $words помещаем слова
    preg_match_all("/[а-яa-z0-9_]+/",$alltext,$words);
```

То есть он не выдал многие результаты, например вернхний TEXT. Не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: Как хорошо, когда под конец напряженного дня, кто-нибудь повеселит ))

> Вообще не понятно что он делает.

А что он должен делать?

Comment: Сформулируйте явно задачу чего Вы хотите добиться. Их неправильного кода это трудно понять.

Comment: Обновил пост, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
// загрузка данных
$alltext=file_get_contents($url);
// убираем пробелы в начале и конце текста
$alltext = trim($alltext);
// удаляем тэги из текста
$alltext = strip_tags($alltext);
// удаляем последовательности вида &lt; &gt; &#1a22; при этом только если длина меньше 9 символов
$alltext = preg_replace('/&[a-z0-9#]{1,9}?;/i', '', $alltext);
// в $words помещаем слова
preg_match_all("/[а-яa-z0-9_]+/i",$alltext,$words);
```

Comment: Я обновил свой первый пост, посмотрите его.

Comment: Забыл модификатор игнора регистра поставить во втором регулярном выражении. Обновил ответ.

Comment: теперь он выдал: text,б,де,мой,ек,ололо,push,pushmy,frogis,die,http,site,ru
не могу понять, почему русский текст не весь выдает.

Comment: С кодировкой что-то не то наверно.

Comment: ммм, оба файла в UTF 8 , в какую лучше преобразовать?

Comment: Можно вот так попробовать.  

    /[а-яА-ЯA-Za-z0-9_]+/

Comment: Да, почти получилось, спасибо. Дальше я это подберу. 
Вот только проблема. При сравнении "уже есть ли это слово в базе" , он пишет ошибку в mysql_fetch_array , видимо он не может русские слова в базе сравнивать.

Comment: "русские слова" /[а-яА-ЯA-Za-z0-9_]+/iu
u - UTF-8

Comment: @арсений игоревич, модификатор /u есть в PHP, но не JavaScript как в рассматриваемом вопросе.